# SSIS how to do a long "if statement" in data flow?

Tags: if-statement, ssis

This is how current table looks:

[image]

In this table,  "Y" shows the test date.

Now I want to add a column called "TestDate", which will show test date according to values in "Monday" ... and "Sunday". The basic logic is like following:

```
IF  MONDAY ='Y'
    TestDays = 'M' ;
else IF TUESDAY  ='Y'
    TestDays ='T' ;
 ....
```

However, I don't know how to do it in SSIS. If I use "?:" in derived column, then it will be too long and too complicated. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Sorry. But thats the only way to do it. You will have to write IIF expression and thats about it.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? File or database? If database, what vendor, edition, etc? Will there be rows that don't have a Y at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use a script component. That way, you can program your logic in a maintainable .NET script.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136118.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181225.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A possibility if you don't want to go down the script route but want to keep you '?:'s short is too split them out.

Have two derived column tasks, the first one to generate a name column for each respective day and the second task to concatenate these name columns together.